# How can I push an object outside a function?

Tags: php, laravel, api

I need to write an API that have all the table column but with the option of skipping the nullable field/column.

somehow the array return empty, can you figured out what happen?

store function ==>

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $dataTable = [];
    function checkifexist($column,$request_name,$request,$dataTable){
        if($request->has($request_name)){
            addData($column,$request_name,$dataTable);
        }
    }
    function addData($column,$request_name,$request,$dataTable){
        // $dataTable[$column] = $request[$request_name];
        array_push($dataTable,array($column => $request[$request_name]));
    }
  
    try {
        addData("example_field","example_field",$request,$dataTable); //required 
          
        checkifexist("example_number_two","example_number_two",$request,$dataTable); 
        //check if the request have this option



        item::create($dataTable);

        $data["success"] = true;
        $data["code"] = 200;
        $data["message"] = "success";
        $data["data"] = ["this is the data you are inputing"=>$dataTable];
    
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        $data["data"] = [];
        $data["success"] = false;
        $data["code"] = 500;
        $data["message"] = $th->getMessage();
    }
    return $data;
}
```

postman request ==>

```
method = "post";
body:{
  example_field:"value"
}
```

result of postman ==>

```
{
    "success": true,
    "code": 200,
    "message": "success",
    "data": {
        "this is the data you are inputing": []
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll probably have to pass the array to the functions by reference. Otherwise the function will create it's own locally scoped copy when it modifies it. (Hence `$dataTable` is an empty array as it was initialized to be)

Comment: As part of OOP, having functions defined in methods isn't the appropriate way of doing this, you should have something like `private` methods to do the processing.

Comment: Pass by reference or have your private methods return the modified array (and don't forget to reassign it in the public method in that case).

Comment: thx to EL_VANJA to give me the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this one work.
i return the data in the function and then replace the array with the new value

Credit to: EL_VANJA

```
    $dataTable = [];
    function addData($column,$request_name,$request,$dataTable){
        $dataTable[$column] = $request[$request_name];
        return $dataTable;
    }
    function checkifexist($column,$request_name,$request,$dataTable){
        if($request->has($request_name)){
           $newData = addData($column,$request_name,$request,$dataTable);
           return $newData;
        }
    }
    $dataTable = addData("item_id","item_id",$request,$dataTable);
    $dataTable = checkifexist("name","name",$request,$dataTable);
```

postman result ==>

```
{
    "success": true,
    "code": 200,
    "message": "success",
    "data": {
        "this is the data you are inputing": {
                                                "ExampleField": "1",
                                                "ExampleFiledTwo": "sdsad"
        }
    }
}
```